# Creating several requests via UNION. MYSQL.mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a task. I did it, but I must create one request for several SELECT by  UNION.
Separately every request is work.
But when I try bind in one - ERROR.

```
SELECT name, age FROM Students ORDER BY age LIMIT 3
UNION
(SELECT name,age FROM Teachers ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT name, duration FROM Courses ORDER BY duration DESC LIMIT 3);
```

I will be pleasure, if somebody help me!

Comment: 1. Make sure the Selected elements in each of the queries are the same or compatible data types and cast them if necessary.  2. Not sure if MySql is finicky about having the same column name in all the queries, but you could `select name, duration as age...` in the 3rd query.  3. Don't use order by in Unions, it's a waste of time.  The merging process will probably reorder them again anyway.  If you want the result in a particular order, wrap the whole thing in another Select with an Order By.  4. If you want to preserve all records from the 3 queries then use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need the bracket around the first select, so that mysql interpreter knows they belong together

Pleas remember that `UNION`will remove duplicates

```
(SELECT name, age FROM Students ORDER BY age LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT name,age FROM Teachers ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT name, duration FROM Courses ORDER BY duration DESC LIMIT 3);
```